# Controlling position of the CSS mirrored text

Tags: html, css, webkit, flip, mirroring

Using code from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433641/flipping-inverting-mirroring-text-using-css-only) question I managed to mirror text but now it's out of the flow of normal text.

```
<style>
span.flip {
        display: block;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Gecko */
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Operah */
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* webkit */
        transform: scaleX(-1); /* standard */
        filter: FlipH; /* IE 6/7/8 */
    }
</style>

<p>Some text <span class="flip">mirror</span> and more tex</p>
```

How can I keep the mirrored text from breaking out from the normal text flow? Which properties control position of the mirrored text?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3433641/632951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` this will make it all in one line:

```
<style>
span.flip {
        display: inline-block;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Gecko */
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Operah */
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* webkit */
        transform: scaleX(-1); /* standard */
        filter: FlipH; /* IE 6/7/8 */
    }
</style>

<p>Some text <span class="flip">mirror</span> and more text</p>​
```

If you want it on a different line, use this:

```
<style>
span.flip {
        display: block;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Gecko */
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Operah */
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* webkit */
        transform: scaleX(-1); /* standard */
        filter: FlipH; /* IE 6/7/8 */
        width: 36px; 
    }
</style>

<p>Some text <span class="flip">mirror</span> and more text</p>​
```

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem. The mirrored text still breaks the flow of normal text - normal text is on one line with the mirrored one on the line below it.

Comment: OH...sorry, i did not know what you meant, i will work on it right now.